# How to load image via CSS in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to load a background image via CSS. My CSS loads with the exception of the image.

I am trying to load the image file via CSS as a Sprite.

The problem:

The image doesnt load via CSS. How do I specify the file path to load the image via CSS?

I have tried a number of different file paths for the image. The image is stored in the WordPress media gallery. The file path is:

```
wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Sprite.png
```

The CSS I am using is:

```
.icon {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
background-image: url("wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Sprite.png");
display: inline-block; 
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing, can you provide a link?

Comment: try adding a `!important` at the end of the line

Comment: You can see the url/path to your image in the wordpress gallery. Did you have your path from there?

Comment: The file path is as above.

Comment: @sebasaenz adding !important should be a last resort, I reckon.

Comment: @theoretisch It's best to call the image with a relative so it doesn't break on localhost or some other non-live url.

Comment: @Nathaniel Flick Yes I know, but his path doesn't looks relative. And if you have the right absolute path its easy to make the realtive path.

Comment: @GavinReynoldson you missed the closing tag ; on  background-image: url(' '); and you need to add your domain before wp-content something like background-image:url('http://www.yourwpsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Sprite.png');

Comment: No @MostafaBaezid do not add the domain to the url, it breaks the theme when it's anywhere but the live server. The path ends up being relative to the style.css file, not /wp-content.

Comment: Is it not just due to not prefixing wp-content with a /? ie background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Sprite.png");

Answer (score 0):

```css
.icon {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x100');
background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

I recommend creating an images directory in your theme and calling it there instead of uploads, especially if the sprite image file goes with your theme. But to answer your question:

To get the image from uploads do this: '../../../wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Sprite.png'

Comment: Reference a theme image in a stylesheet: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188725/how-to-reference-a-theme-image-in-a-stylesheet

Comment: I just noticed you are calling a sprite and as such it's made up of more than one image. That means when you call the sprite you also have to call coordinates so the background attribute knows what part of the sprite image to call. also add "background-repeat: no-repeat" so background shows the sprite only once. Examples here: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ so you need to set background-position: 0 0; for example then set the height and width, and those H and W dimensions are based on the "background-position" setting.

Answer (score 0):

in your css part background-image have no closing tag. it should be like this.  background-image:url('');

second let me show you an example. Here is demo [wordpress](https://mediashark.com.au/) website. In this site here is the [logo](https://mediashark.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/mediashark-s200.png) . If we use this logo as your icon

```css
 .icon {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
background-image: url("https://mediashark.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/logo-200-1.png");
display: inline-block; 
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<span><i class="icon"></i>TEST</span>
```